# DevExpress ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I have the following event handler in my view:

```
private void ComboBoxEdit_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var sb = ((ComboBoxEdit)sender).SelectedText;
  model.SearchBy = sb;
  SearchItem.Label = sb;
}
```

The combo items are hard-coded in XAML:

```
  <dxe:ComboBoxEdit SelectedIndex="0" SelectedIndexChanged="ComboBoxEdit_SelectedIndexChanged" Height="22">
    <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem Content="Emp. No." />
    <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem Content="Id No." />
    <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem Content="Surname" />       
  </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
```

Yet when I select "Id.No." and the event fires, `SelectedText` returns "Emp.No.", and always the previous item in the list. Yet I'm not working directly with index (except to set selected to 0 in markup), so although this looks like a 1 vs 0 error, it shouldn't be. Surely the event "Changed" should get the value I select in the UI, vs. "Changing",which could get the previous value?

Comment: I would definitely expect the `SelectedText` property to be the same as the currently selected item. Have you tried the `SelectedItem` property instead?

Comment: @GeorgeHowarth Funny, but SelectedItem gives the correct content. Add an answer and I'll accept, thanks.

Comment: I don't think it warrants an entire answer :) It was just a suggestion to workaround to something that _should_ actually work. Either I've misunderstood what `SelectedIndexChanged` does or it's a bug in their API.

Comment: I will log it with them. Took a lot to persuade people to buy in the first place, based on good aspx experiences.

Answer (score 0):

PopupClosed="CmbReportType_PopupClosed"

```
    private void CmbReportType_PopupClosed(object sender, ClosePopupEventArgs e)
    {
        var cBox = sender as ComboBoxEdit;
        if (cBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            var selectedItemText = cBox.SelectedText;
        }
    }
```